# Ensemble classification with Rigetti and Qiskit devices : Params.npy

Tags: programming, pennylane

I want ask how the params.npy variable were obtained? It would be great if you provide the codes for my better understanding.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import dask

n_classes = 2 #label 
n_layers = 2
# the first index is for the two models
params = torch.tensor(np.random.random((2, n_layers, n_wires, 3)), requires_grad=True)
iteration = 1

def softmax_ensemble(params, x_point=None):
    results = [q(params, x=x_point) for q in qnodes]
    softmax = torch.nn.functional.softmax(results, dim=1)
    choice = torch.where(softmax == torch.max(softmax))[0][0]
    return softmax[choice]

def cost(params, y_point, x_point=None):
    return torch.sum(torch.abs(softmax_ensemble(params, x_point=x_point) - y_point))

y_soft = torch.tensor(tf.one_hot(y_train, n_classes).numpy(), requires_grad=True)

opt = torch.optim.Adam([params], lr = 0.1) #learning rate 

for x_point, y_point in zip(x_train, y_soft):
    opt.zero_grad()
    c = cost(params, y_point=y_point, x_point=x_point)
    c.backward()
    opt.step()
    if iteration % 10 == 0 and iteration > 0:
        print("Iteration : ", iteration)
    iteration += 1
```

output :
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.